# When using ZipOutputStream to create an ODT file in java fails to open in OpenOffice

Tags: java, zip, odt, opendocument, zipoutputstream

I have the following method to add zip entries to a ZipOutputStream:

```
    private void addFile(String filename, byte[] bytes, ZipOutputStream zos, boolean encrypt) throws IOException {
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
        if (encrypt) {
            entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.DEFLATED);
        } else {
            entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
            CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
            crc32.update(bytes);
            entry.setCrc(crc32.getValue());
            entry.setSize(bytes.length);
            entry.setCompressedSize(bytes.length);
        }
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(bytes);
        zos.flush();
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
```

...and I use it opening a new ZipOutputStream (`ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(path))));`), setting its method to DEFLATED (`zos.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);`) and then calling for the following files (in order):

1. "mimetype" (for this file, I set the ZipEntry method to STORED)
2. "manifest.xml" in a subfolder called "META-INF" (META-INF/manifest.xml)
3. "content.xml"
4. "styles.xml"
5. "meta.xml"
6. "thumbnail.png" in a subfolder called "Thumbnails" ("Thumbnails/thumbnail.png")
7. "settings.xml"

...finally, I call the close method for the ZipOutputStream (`zos.close();`).

If I try to open it directly with OpenOffice, it ask me what kind of file I'm trying to open, it says that the file is corrupted and finally it opens the file... but If I unzip the file (I'm using winrar) and then I zip again with the same tool (winrar, I mean) without any change, OpenOffice is able to open without any problem the document...

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds a bit strange.  Are you handling exceptions **properly**?

Comment: I have a big "try-catch" surrounding all the code, and there are no exceptions.

Comment: Do you have any little "try-catches" that are squashing exceptions?  (I asked if you were handling exceptions *properly* ... )

Answer (score 0):

```
**I don't see a ZipEntry for the Directory META-INF/ to be added in your list of files, is the manifest.xml file ending up in the root directory? then again, that's not the problem I guessing.**

> 1. "mimetype" (for this file, I set the ZipEntry method to STORED)
> 2. "manifest.xml" in a subfolder called "META-INF" (META-INF/manifest.xml)
> 3. "content.xml"
> 4. "styles.xml"
> 5. "meta.xml"
> 6. "thumbnail.png" in a subfolder called "Thumbnails" ("Thumbnails/thumbnail.png")
> 7. "settings.xml"

*That's why OO is freaking out for a moment and the and when you open it in winrar, winZip or any other zip utility and re-zip it, the utility will create the entry for the directories in the zipFile. by noticing that the file URL conforms to a valid path on the current OS, I beat if you took the bad zip file with not directory entries and opened in OO it may not be able to recover because the File.Separator is leaning the other way.*

*So In the case where you open it right in OO and it can't determine what type of content its opening maybe because it can't locate the manifest.xml which it would be expecting to unpack into the META-INF/ directory.*

*This causes a chain side effect. So when files that are inside directories are just seen as files with path "Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml" for example.  But because the Name or the String Representation of the Path does not include actual folders, its just a string that looks like a path and so OO thinks "Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml" is the name of the file. It does not recognize it as two directories with a file init.*


**so why does zip utility or OO it self fix it at some point?**

*what's most likely going on is when OO unpacks the files tries to find the manifest.xml named entry, but it cant find it there is a "META-INF/manifest.xml" named entry or resource but it does a compare == 0 and withInString to find the keys.*

*And this gets fixed when the application(s) write the entry "META-INF/manifest.xml" back into a zipped file, it because of the "/" knows that this is a path that contains directories and adds the directories as entries in the zip file, so when it reopens or when it recovers by trying to save-reload the document it now has a directory META-INF/ as a entry it adds that first then the manifest.xml file into that dir and the ODF structure is what it likes*

**Important: When Adding files Images, Data, Video, Audio or any type you should either: 
- Create a ZipEntry for each folder in the path. for /MyCustomImgDir/Trip/swimming.png
     -- Entry Name: MyCustomImgDir/ should be added as a directory entry
     -- and Entry Name: MyCustomImgDir/Trip/ should be added another directory entry
- OR you can add the file in the Meta-Inf/manifest.xml file and provide the full-path location so, OO can find-and-put it in the proper place.


**********************************************************************************
* Optianl Reading for more detail if you're not familir with zip files and paths *
**********************************************************************************
*  Why the below section? - I spent many years working on a platform that used   *
*                           the ODF format, when the API was limited and we were *
*                           and the only way to do many things was to rip aprt the*
*                            xml and add-delete-modify-move around the bytes all over*
*                           Major pain in the butt, I just want to same someonea few weeks*
*                           heck. (I can say that right?)
**********************************************************************************


So to further discuss and more details, Ex: I have a file.ods and when I list the contents of the file below is what I get with 15 files

kumar@PareshMacBookPro~/temp/eKits/variableData>unzip -l ../variabledata.ods 
Archive:  ../variabledata.ods
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
       46  04-11-08 18:36   mimetype
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/statusbar/
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/floater/
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/popupmenu/
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/progressbar/
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/menubar/
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/toolbar/
        0  04-11-08 18:36   Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/
    61403  04-11-08 18:36   content.xml
     6909  04-11-08 18:36   styles.xml
     1037  04-11-08 18:36   meta.xml
     1355  04-11-08 18:36   Thumbnails/thumbnail.png
     7668  04-11-08 18:36   settings.xml
     1873  04-11-08 18:36   META-INF/manifest.xml
 --------                   -------
    80291                   15 files


*****************************************************************************
and Unziping it produces: (15 files, like it listed)

kumar@PareshMacBookPro~/temp/eKits>unzip -d variabledata variabledata.ods
Archive:  variabledata.ods
 extracting:/mimetype   
   creating:/Configurations2/statusbar/
  inflating:/Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml  
   creating:/Configurations2/floater/
   creating:/Configurations2/popupmenu/
   creating:/Configurations2/progressbar/
   creating:/Configurations2/menubar/
   creating:/Configurations2/toolbar/
   creating:/Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/
  inflating:/content.xml  
  inflating:/styles.xml  
 extracting:/meta.xml   
  inflating:/Thumbnails/thumbnail.png  
  inflating:/settings.xml  
  inflating:/META-INF/manifest.xml

*****************************************************************************
so from my unzipped files and folders I rezip it without any change and looking at results show:

kumar@PareshMacBookPro~/temp/eKits/variableData>zip -ru newDocZip.zip *
    zip warning: newDocZip.zip not found or empty
  adding: Configurations2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/accelerator/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/floater/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/images/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/menubar/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/popupmenu/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/progressbar/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/statusbar/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Configurations2/toolbar/ (stored 0%)
  adding: META-INF/ (stored 0%)
  adding: META-INF/manifest.xml (deflated 83%)
  adding: Thumbnails/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Thumbnails/thumbnail.png (deflated 44%)
  adding: content.xml (deflated 89%)
  adding: meta.xml (deflated 59%)
  adding: mimetype (deflated 4%)
  adding: settings.xml (deflated 87%)
  adding: styles.xml (deflated 78%)

******************************************************************************
*****now there are 20 entries*******************
Why OO does not include a ZipEntry for folder that are in the middle of a path:

Example there is an entry at: Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml
but you do not see entries for directories:
 - Configurations2/
and
 - Configurations2/accelerator
Why Because it know when it keeps 

******************************************************************************

** Notice that mimetype is the first ZipEntry in the ZipFile created by OO and its anywhere and where ever when created by a zip utility**

*Notice the META-INF/ and Thumbnails/ other folders that are added in order (<em>parent dir before children's<em>)!*

**So lets check out the mimetype of the .ods and .zip file with command line util:**

kumar@PareshMacBookPro~/temp/eKits>file --mime variabledata.ods 
variabledata.ods: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet; charset=binary

*you see that the mimetype shows as a application/spreadsheet and when you do the same for the new zip file (just rezipped unzipped ods content by zip util no changes to paths or files) you get:*
******************************************************************************

kumar@PareshMacBookPro~/temp/eKits/variabledata>file --mime newDoc.zip 
newDoc.zip: application/zip; charset=binary

*it's no loger a spreadsheet it is an actual zip file content type.*
******************************************************************************

*Also just for fun you may want to output the raw bytes in a command line or consol by just 'cat' or 'head' or 'print' on the same files. You get trash but somethings there if look closer.*
******************************************************************************


kumar@PareshMacBookPro~/temp/eKits/variabledata>head ../variabledata.ods 
PK???8?l9?.<em>mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet<em>PK???8Configurations2/statusbar/???8'

**and re-zipped file, we've lost the content-type header and much more.**
******************************************************************************

kumar@PareshMacBookPro~/temp/eKits/variabledata>head newDoc.ods 
PK
u??@Configurations2/UT  ??  PF? Pux
                                           ?PK

******************************************************************************
***What to watch out for***
******************************************************************************

**It is not nesserry to have the content-type of the zip file as the <em>mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet<em> it can be <em>applicatoin/zip<em> and openOffice will still be able to use it. The content-type is important to have there and correct, but for OpenOffice-Documents its more important to have the mimetype file in the root dir and have the META-INF/manifest.xml file in the directory META-INF/.  

- The application does not look at the extension to determine the file type the OS does to launch the linked application for that extension, and if there is non it tries to find the content-type from the file header and find the appropriate application to handel file. Note that you can assign .txt or .jpeg to open with openOffice and it will open it even though its not a zip file.

- OO tries to start by looking at the file header to find the content-type first but it can live with out it.

- It then tries to find manifest.xml file. It placed it there so it can trust it. From that file It makes a check list of stuff listed in the manifest.xml file and cross checks it against the actual files (ZipEntires) extracted from the ZippedFile.
  <em>Listed directories in the manifest.xml that are not in the zipContent as entries won't cause a problem long as its not expecting a file in that directory.<em>

- When it fails to read the file header (because its application/zip type), and the it does not have a mimetype.  It will wiggout and want to find out really bad what type this file is. Or if there is file (i.e. ZipEntry) missing or it thinks its missing becuase the name is full string literal with the full path it can't resolve it to a ZipEntry Name Key.  Even though, the real readable binary data is in the zip file, it will think something is wrong and ask to restore it but reproduce the zip content the best way it can.

- The ODF file is a zip format file but it's picky and expect things to in a certain place.  **

******************************************************************************
**So whats the fix to not have this problem? Simply: You need to recursively walk the directories adding sub-dirs and files all of them.**
******************************************************************************

**In more detail:**
1. start at the root directory
2. RootDirectory.listfiles()
2a. if the entry from listfile() 
    2a-1) if aFile from the list is a real file then add that as the zipentry as you would
      * then move on to the next item in your listfiles()
    2a-2) if aFile from the list is a directory you need to add that as a entry in the zipfile as a dir by appending "/" at the end of the path.
      * then again do a listfiles() on the directory to get files and dirs for the directory you just added and restart step 1. with the sub-directory as the RootDirectory and add its dirs and sub-dirs and files.

******************************************************************************
*  other note to keep in mind:
******************************************************************************
** Of course there is the matter of using the right Encoding for the xml files and other files.  Windows defualts to ios-8859-1 and Linux/Unix/Mac defaults to UTF-8 when new OutputSteams and writers are create. so if somethings working in nix and not winders, good place to look is at your streams**
******************************************************************************

Thanks, I hope you had as much fun reading this as I did writing it.  I just hope it makes sense.

ps - sorry about the formatting job.
```

Comment: And do I need to create the root directory ("/" or "./")?

Comment: No the zip file name is usually used when zip unzip. You can creat the zip and safly rename the file to anything, but unzipping will use the new name. We use to append time, processedby, state and have the file name reflect the current state and history in the file name.

Comment: Good luck hope you can nail it. Also it may not matter but I did have issues if did a write with all the data at once, it's a blocking call so if your zipping a 200Mb image your app can freezz for a bit.  I never had problem after I started to read/write 1024 bytes at a time.

Comment: right now I'm creating the following entries:

· "mimetype"
· "Thumbnails/"
· "META-INF/"
· "META-INF/manifest.xml"
· "content.xml"
· "styles.xml"
· "meta.xml"
· "settings.xml"
· "Thumbnails/thumbnail.png"

...but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: I am not near my laptop and can't scroll through my code, but check this out it's good as is gets, you should be able to use it as is. Just besure to get mime file as the first entry.

Comment: Oh I guess I should supply what to check out: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-zip-a-directory-and-all-its-contents.html

Comment: Oh and I don't think you should be writing any bytes or even call the zip.write( bytes ) when your processing a directory entry. As as the output shoes from my prior samples of the zipped content you just need to ensure paths are relative and your not over shooting your writes with extra or not supplying the amount of bytes you are asking to be placed by write call.  If you don't have anything sensative data in your oo doc you can email the zip your ending up with and send it over with fixing it trying to open it.  Paresh@kuyash.com

Comment: Oh and one more quick though your path as a string your passing to ZipEntey( path ) is that "/home/user/you/content2compress/content.xml" or is it "context.xml" ? Hope your chopping everything up to the content2compress/ including the / after root dir. So you shouldn't have "/content.xml" as the zipEntey name or the path passed in.

Comment: I have sent you a sample odt file created with my code..., If you have an idea... Thanks!

Comment: @raul_herranz Hay, Did you get this working properly? I got your first email but I have not seen a second email with a new odt file.  Sorry I haven't followed up on this been a little busy.

Comment: here is my answer for your question "how big of a buffer are you using to write to your zipoutputstream?":

I have tried with different buffer sizes: 1024, 2048, 4096 and with the complete files without buffering... and I allways get the same different size after zip the files...

Answer (score 0):

Raul,

Looks like your zip file is intact and correct, so its not the zip process that causing the problem.

The problem is that the doctype dtd location is invalid when your process creates the xml file for maniest.xml file.

The line in manifest.xml:

And also you have a manifest.rdf file in the root of the zip which throwing OO off when trying to put stuff back together.  I don't know process you are using to create the OpenOffice document XML output, but thats where the problem is.  You need to make sure the path for the DTD is correct or remove the DOCTYPE from the XML files.

Here is how you can manually fix the OpenOffice ODT file:

- Remove the Manifest.rdf from zip root dir
- Remove the DOCTYPE line from META-INF/menifest.xml
- Add the manifest entries for the directories listed below (Note the difference in the Configurations2 entry)

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/statusbar/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/accelerator/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/floater/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/popupmenu/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/progressbar/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/toolpanel/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/menubar/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/toolbar/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/"/>

  < manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/images/"/>

**< manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="application/vnd.sun.xml.ui.configuration" manifest:full-path="Configurations2/"/>**

I think the winrar may be taking care of fixing the dtd path issues for you. And so does open office when it repairs it. OO can handel not having the DTD defined, it know what to look for but it doesn't like bad DTD's

Hope that fixes it for you.  I like to know what your using to write the XML though.

Comment: I did send you an odt file created with OpenOffice and an odt file created with my code after coding your fixes... as you can see, there are some differences in the size of some compressed elements... do you know why? maybe a problem with the java zip implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the problem can be on Windows where you provide backslashes in the filename you pass to the ZipEntry constructor.
I change them to forward slashes and after that OpenOffice no longer complains about the odt being corrupt

Answer (score 0):

in my case. I replace

```
zos.flush();
zos.closeEntry();
```

by =>

```
zos.finish()
```